# WordPress role-based login redirection does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I followed instructions online to add a function to my `functions.php` file of my child theme, which should redirect users of certain roles to specific URLs.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

I've thoroughly re-analyzed my code and compared it to various solutions online, yet, I can't get it to take any effect on my site.

My code:

```
// Custom successful login redirect based on user role
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    // is there a user to check?
    global $user;
    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
        // check for 'company' user role and redirect in case
        if (in_array('company', $user->roles)) {
          $redirect_to = home_url('/arbeitskraft-finden/');
        // check for 'worker' user role and redirect in case
        } elseif (in_array('worker', $user->roles)) {
          $redirect_to = home_url('/wp-admin/chat/');
        // otherwise, redirect to wp-admin
        } else {
          $redirect_to = home_url('/wp-admin/');
        }
    } else {
      return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
// END Custom successful login redirect based on user role
```

Expected results:

- users with the role "company" get redirected to /arbeitskraft-finden/
- users with the role "worker" get redirected to /wp-admin/chat/
- users with other roles get redirected to /wp-admin/

Comment: Try this: [enable the debug log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), then add the following right after `global $user;`: `error_log( print_r($user->roles, true) );` and try logging in again. Then check the contents of your `debug.log` file, what does it say?

Comment: Have you tried using Xdebug, it might help you finding the problem very rapidly, I do recommend you to do that. So you can use breakpoints and lear what is happening in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the post editing and the recommended solution @cabrerahector. I altered the file as suggested by you. However, when I log in, no debug.log file appears in `/wp-config/`. I tried multiple times (logging in). It seems like my code isn't executed? However, everything else in the same `functions.php` seems to work. Any other ideas?
@moplin thank you for your suggestion also. Currently, I am not using a sophisticated, local development environment. I haven't used xdebug so far and after reading into it for an hour or so, I think this is a last resort option for now.

Comment: The debug.log file should be in `/wp-content` (was that a typo?) Try creating the file manually and repeat the steps from above. If the file is empty then I'd check if the filter hook you're is the right one.

Comment: @cabrerahector that was a type indeed. After creating the log file manually, still, nothing was logged. 
However, I found the solution to my problem, and I'll add a new answer with the code. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back to the initial source of information that I've used, the WordPress codex: [Link to the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)

I realised that the variable `$user` isn't defined globally inside the function there. I have no idea how it came that I had that in my code.

After removing it, and also after removing the second `else` for the first `if` statement, the code works and looks like this:

```
// Custom successful login redirect based on user role
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
  // is there a user to check?
  if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
      // check for 'company' user role and redirect in case
      if (in_array('company', $user->roles)) {
        $redirect_to = home_url('/arbeitskraft-finden/');
      // check for 'worker' user role and redirect in case
      } elseif (in_array('worker', $user->roles)) {
        $redirect_to = home_url('/wp-admin/chat/');
      // otherwise, redirect to wp-admin
      } else {
        $redirect_to = home_url('/wp-admin/');
      }
  } 
  return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
// END Custom successful login redirect based on user role
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return variable **$redirect_to** outside **else** condition because when you check if user role is set or not, you are only assigning a value to that variable. Not returning it. please try this code

```
// Custom successful login redirect based on user role
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    // is there a user to check?
    global $user;
    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
        // check for 'company' user role and redirect in case
        if (in_array('company', $user->roles)) {
          $redirect_to = home_url('/arbeitskraft-finden/');
        // check for 'worker' user role and redirect in case
        } elseif (in_array('worker', $user->roles)) {
          $redirect_to = home_url('/wp-admin/chat/');
        // otherwise, redirect to wp-admin
        } else {
          $redirect_to = home_url('/wp-admin/');
        }

    } 
      return $redirect_to;

}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
// END Custom successful login redirect based on user role
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @IncipientInfo
I tried with this code, but it didn't work. However, I found the solution and will post it in a new answer.